# Does calling the property .id automatically convert _id to a string format?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently have something like this in my mongoose application:

```
const user = await User.findById(request.params.id)
```

Whenever I `console.log(user)`, I get the entire document object, alongside the `_id: new ObjectId("idstring")` property. There is no reference to `id` but rather to just `_id`.

However when I `console.log(user.id)` I get the returned _id in string format.

How is this possible? Do mongoose models automatically convert the objectID to a string when you call "id" to the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an id virtual getter by default
> which returns the documents _id field cast to a string, or in the case
> of ObjectIds, its hexString.

Because of the virtuals, you are getting the results. So, id is a getter that gives the string's representation of the field `_id`.

Check [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id) for documentation.

Comment: This is why I need to better learn to start and read through documentation. Am a beginner full stack dev. Anyways, thanks a ton. Makes so much sense now!!

Comment: You can accept the answer if that's what you wanted to understand. So, future users can refer it.